# Ember store not working as expected

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using ember v1.10 and ember data v1.0.0-beta.15 on an existing project. I have a service that returns an object that has a message string and an array of publishable ids. As follows:

```
data: [{"Message":"Example 1 cannot be published the following items to be published",
  "PublisherIds":[
    "b9b77872-6954-404f-b451-b5a1938b2fa8",
    "030b39de-5746-4ed4-9e17-e86bb49be164"]
},
{"Message":"Example 2 cannot be published items to be published",
      "PublisherIds":[
        "b9b77872-6954-404f-b451-b5a1938b2fa8",
        "030b39de-5746-4ed4-9e17-e86bb49be164"]
}]
```

In my controller, I  want to iterate through the publisher ids and use them to get all the other data associated with the items from the model called 'publishable' that is already in my store and push them in to an array so I can display them in a table in my template.

My attempt:

```
        var _this = this;

        data.forEach(function(d){
            var items = [];
            d.PublisherIds.forEach(function(a){
                var temp = _this.store.find('publishable', a);
                d.items.push(temp);
            });

        } );
```

Unfortunately the store.find doesn't seem to work. I'm not getting the actual records and I can't push them into an array. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/ for the format expected by the several adapters?

Comment: And can you mention which version of Ember Data you are using?

Comment: I'm using ember data 1.0.0-beta.15, thanks for taking a look. the store just returns some empty data wrappers and empty classes

Comment: And you are sure that `a` in the `_this.store-find` line holds the correct value, a publishable ID?

Comment: hey torazaburo, yes 'a' holds the publisherid from the data and loops through these without issue. the store.find just isn't grabbing the record... i'm not sure why